# Output of hashmap

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

Till now I was very much clear about hashmap internal working.But seeing the below snippet of code I am little bit confused.

In the following code, my class's `equals()` method always returns false. Therefore I would expect `HashMap.get()` to **never** find a key of that class.

Can someone please explain me. In the get method I know it will calculate the hashcode and it will find the exact bucket but as equals is returning false how can it return 3?

```
    package com.vikash.Theory.CollectionsFramework;

    public class Emp {

        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;

        public Emp(String firstName,String lastName) {
            this.firstName=firstName;
            this.lastName=lastName;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public int hashCode() {
            return firstName.hashCode()+lastName.hashCode();
        }

        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            return false;
        }
    }


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<Object,Integer> map=new HashMap<Object,Integer>();
        Emp e1=new Emp("Vikash","Mishra");
        Emp e2=new Emp("Mishra","Vikash");
        Emp e3=new Emp("Mishra","Vikash");
        map.put(e1, 1);
        map.put(e2, 2);
        map.put(e3, 3);
        /*e2.setFirstName("Vikash");
        e2.setLastName("Mishra");*/
        System.out.println("Size of the map is:"+map.size());
        System.out.println(map.get(e3)); } }
```

Comment: hint: **Hash**Map

Comment: Well it's returning 3 because you're putting 3 non-equal keys in... what would you expect it to return, and why?

Comment: His point is that since `equals()` always returns `false`, he'd expect `get()` to return null.

Comment: @slim Yes that what I understood.But I got the answer now after you explained Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code of HashMap reveals all:

```
322      if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)))
323                 return e.value;
```

It tests for `e.key == key` *before* it tests for `key.equals(e.key)`.

In general, having a buggy `equals()` causes all kinds of confusing behaviour in Java, so it's very wise to avoid doing so. One part of the `equals()` contract is that `x.equals(x)` should always be `true`.

Comment: Is the result implementation-dependent then?

Comment: Potentially. I don't think any standard says the implementation should do the == test.

Comment: @PM77-1 The result of contract-breaking code is always _unspecified_ and among other things that also implies implementation dependence.

Answer (score -2):

1)in your hashcode() you have not used equals() method of emp class

2)instead,your hashcode() is using already implemented hashcode() of String class BECAUSE firstname and lastname are of type string.

3)in your case even if both keys are same they will have different hashcode()
beacuse you have not  defined that when the keys will be same they should have same hashcode()

4) equals() method is not called in hashcode() automagically but instead  it has to be called explicitly  to implement  hashcode() and ultimately the hashmap in **DESIRED WAY**

this is what i think please may be the reason that is working properly even 
if you have a buggy equals() method